how can i cut a map in Maplibre?
I want to render the map only where the data is.
The bounds I applied to map-tile.json worked, but I don't know how to handle background(in map-style.json).
enter image description here 
enter image description here 
enter image description here 

Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text (using code formatting), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and many more reasons. Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data. See [mre] on what code is required.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
